# Flash на 100% ширины, но чтоб не растягивалась в высоту

Tags: flash, html, css

Есть Flash, например, [такая](http://rghost.ru/35889848) (нарисовал для теста).

Нужно сделать так, чтоб она растягивалась по всей ширине, но чтоб не было пустых мест между флеш и контентом. Выглядеть должно так

[image]

но при уменьшении окна все сбивается

[image]

Как это можно исправить?

[Страница](http://trutee.ru/test4/).

Comment: Может можно средствами java или чего еще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1 вариант: делаем флеш с высотой больше любого возможного блока, исходя из возможной высоты экрана, убираем в контейнер с hidden:overflow, ставим ему меньший z-index:, чем у блока ниже. Соответственно, требует тщательного вымеривания и аккуратного расположения содержимого самой флэшки.
2. 2 вариант: делаем подложку для флэшки, которая визуально её растянет. Не факт, что применимо.
3. 3 вариант: пользуемся передачей данных во флэш и подгоняем её размеры при помощи AS изнутри и JS снаружи. SWFObject также может быть полезен.